# iOS app : Hardcoded to Storyboard

Tags: ios7, storyboard, scene

I'm trying to transform an app hardcoded, not using storyboard ( view/design/segue harcoded ) to a view with storyboard/scene.
So I'm working on an app that has several functions (login/out, home, notify, data) that majority have similar layout : the same header picture, similar input fields, etc.

So I wonder if there is a solution to transform it into a storyboard with all view of the app ?
Or everything has to be re-coded ?

Comment: You must re-do it in Storyboard.

Comment: An App which doesn't use storyboards isn't hardcoded. This term is used for something else. Why do you want to change that. Coded UI is perfectly fine and in some cases even faster than storyboard projects.

Comment: Because I'm in a stage and I thought maybe it can be good for exemple for simplify the creation of views of an application, synthesize application, highlighting the relationship between views ?